# Create multiple output dataframes from multiple input dataframes in R in a generalizable way

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have `n` input dataframes, each of which has one `TimeStamp` column + `k` numeric value columns.

I want to convert them into `k` output dataframes each of them will have one `TimeStamp` column + `n` numeric value columns, so that the numeric column `i` of output dataframe `j` will have values from the numeric column `j` of input dataframe `i` (column indices exclude the `TimeStamp` column, which is the first column) and the missing `TimeStamp`s should be filled with NAs.

The first column in these dataframes is always the `TimeStamp` column (where the `TimeStamp`s are overlapped),

Number of rows in the input dataframes are different (may have different `TimeStamp`).

For example, each of the dataframes `d1, d2` for `n=2` have the following structure (one sample dataframe `d1` is shown below for `k=4`, `k` can be arbitrary but will be same for each dataframe) and each of them is stored in separate csv files:

```
d1 <- structure(list(TimeStamp = structure(1:6, .Label = c("2016-12-20 10:17:20", "2016-12-20 10:19:20", "2016-12-20 10:19:40", "2016-12-20 10:20:00", "2016-12-20 10:20:20", "2016-12-20 10:20:40", "2016-12-20 10:21:00", 
"2016-12-20 10:21:20", "2016-12-20 10:21:40", "2016-12-20 10:22:00", 
"2016-12-20 10:22:20", "2016-12-20 10:22:40", "2016-12-20 10:23:00", 
"2016-12-20 10:23:20", "2016-12-20 10:23:40", "2016-12-20 10:24:00", 
"2016-12-20 10:24:20", "2016-12-20 10:24:40", "2016-12-20 10:25:00", 
"2016-12-20 10:25:20", "2016-12-20 10:25:40", "2016-12-20 10:26:00", 
"2016-12-20 10:26:20", "2016-12-20 10:26:40", "2016-12-20 10:27:00", 
"2016-12-20 10:27:20", "2016-12-20 10:27:40", "2016-12-20 10:28:00", 
"2016-12-20 10:28:20", "2016-12-20 10:28:40", "2016-12-20 10:29:00", 
"2016-12-20 10:29:20", "2016-12-20 10:29:40", "2016-12-20 10:30:00", 
"2016-12-20 10:30:20", "2016-12-20 10:30:40", "2016-12-20 10:31:00", 
"2016-12-20 10:31:20", "2016-12-20 10:31:40", "2016-12-20 10:32:00", 
"2016-12-20 10:32:20", "2016-12-20 10:32:40", "2016-12-20 10:33:00", 
"2016-12-20 10:33:20", "2016-12-20 10:33:40", "2016-12-20 10:34:00", 
"2016-12-20 10:34:20", "2016-12-20 10:34:40", "2016-12-20 10:35:00", 
"2016-12-20 10:35:20", "2016-12-20 10:35:40", "2016-12-20 10:36:00", 
"2016-12-20 10:37:00", "2016-12-20 10:37:20", "2016-12-20 10:37:40", 
"2016-12-20 10:38:00", "2016-12-20 10:38:20", "2016-12-20 10:40:40", 
"2016-12-20 10:41:20", "2016-12-20 10:41:40", "2016-12-20 10:44:20", 
"2016-12-20 10:44:40", "2016-12-20 10:46:00", "2016-12-20 10:49:40", 
"2016-12-20 10:50:00", "2016-12-20 10:50:20", "2016-12-20 10:55:00", 
"2016-12-20 10:56:00", "2016-12-20 10:57:20", "2016-12-20 10:59:20", 
"2016-12-20 10:59:40", "2016-12-20 11:00:20", "2016-12-20 11:01:20", 
"2016-12-20 11:05:40", "2016-12-20 11:06:00", "2016-12-20 11:07:20", 
"2016-12-20 11:08:20", "2016-12-20 11:08:40", "2016-12-20 11:11:40", 
"2016-12-20 11:12:00", "2016-12-20 11:14:20", "2016-12-20 11:14:40", 
"2016-12-20 11:15:00", "2016-12-20 11:15:20", "2016-12-20 11:15:40", 
"2016-12-20 11:16:00", "2016-12-20 11:16:20", "2016-12-20 11:18:20", 
"2016-12-20 11:18:40", "2016-12-20 11:19:00", "2016-12-20 11:19:20", 
"2016-12-20 11:19:40", "2016-12-20 11:21:20", "2016-12-20 11:21:40", 
"2016-12-20 11:22:20", "2016-12-20 11:22:40", "2016-12-20 11:23:00", 
"2016-12-20 11:23:20", "2016-12-20 11:25:00", "2016-12-20 11:25:20", 
"2016-12-20 11:26:00", "2016-12-20 11:26:40", "2016-12-20 11:27:00", 
"2016-12-20 11:27:20", "2016-12-20 11:27:40", "2016-12-20 11:28:00", 
"2016-12-20 11:28:20", "2016-12-20 11:28:40", "2016-12-20 11:34:40", 
"2016-12-20 11:36:20", "2016-12-20 11:36:40", "2016-12-20 11:41:00", 
"2016-12-20 11:41:20", "2016-12-20 11:42:20", "2016-12-20 11:42:40", 
"2016-12-20 11:46:40", "2016-12-20 11:47:00", "2016-12-20 11:47:20", 
"2016-12-20 11:47:40", "2016-12-20 11:48:00", "2016-12-20 11:48:20", 
"2016-12-20 11:48:40", "2016-12-20 11:54:00", "2016-12-20 11:54:20", 
"2016-12-20 11:57:40", "2016-12-20 12:00:00", "2016-12-20 12:00:40", 
"2016-12-20 12:01:00", "2016-12-20 12:01:20", "2016-12-20 12:01:40", 
"2016-12-20 12:02:20", "2016-12-20 12:02:40", "2016-12-20 12:03:00", 
"2016-12-20 12:03:20", "2016-12-20 12:03:40", "2016-12-20 12:07:00", 
"2016-12-20 12:07:20", "2016-12-20 12:07:40", "2016-12-20 12:08:00", 
"2016-12-20 12:08:20", "2016-12-20 12:10:20", "2016-12-20 12:10:40"
), class = "factor"), b1 = c(-76L, 0L, 0L, -76L, -80L, -81L), 
    b2 = c(0L, -74L, -79L, -73L, -79L, -77L), b3 = c(0L, 0L, 
    -88L, -88L, -91L, 0L), b4 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, -78L, -80L, -78L
    )), .Names = c("TimeStamp", "b1", "b2", "b3", "b4"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame") 

head(d1)
#            TimeStamp  b1  b2  b3  b4
#1 2016-12-20 10:17:20 -76   0   0   0
#2 2016-12-20 10:19:20   0 -74   0   0
#3 2016-12-20 10:19:40   0 -79 -88   0
#4 2016-12-20 10:20:00 -76 -73 -88 -78
#5 2016-12-20 10:20:20 -80 -79 -91 -80
#6 2016-12-20 10:20:40 -81 -77   0 -78

d2 <- structure(list(TimeStamp = structure(137:142, .Label = c("2016-12-20 10:17:20", 
"2016-12-20 10:19:20", "2016-12-20 10:19:40", "2016-12-20 10:20:00", 
"2016-12-20 10:20:20", "2016-12-20 10:20:40", "2016-12-20 10:21:00", 
"2016-12-20 10:21:20", "2016-12-20 10:21:40", "2016-12-20 10:22:00", 
"2016-12-20 10:22:20", "2016-12-20 10:22:40", "2016-12-20 10:23:00", 
"2016-12-20 10:23:20", "2016-12-20 10:23:40", "2016-12-20 10:24:00", 
"2016-12-20 10:24:20", "2016-12-20 10:24:40", "2016-12-20 10:25:00", 
"2016-12-20 10:25:20", "2016-12-20 10:25:40", "2016-12-20 10:26:00", 
"2016-12-20 10:26:20", "2016-12-20 10:26:40", "2016-12-20 10:27:00", 
"2016-12-20 10:27:20", "2016-12-20 10:27:40", "2016-12-20 10:28:00", 
"2016-12-20 10:28:20", "2016-12-20 10:28:40", "2016-12-20 10:29:00", 
"2016-12-20 10:29:20", "2016-12-20 10:29:40", "2016-12-20 10:30:00", 
"2016-12-20 10:30:20", "2016-12-20 10:30:40", "2016-12-20 10:31:00", 
"2016-12-20 10:31:20", "2016-12-20 10:31:40", "2016-12-20 10:32:00", 
"2016-12-20 10:32:20", "2016-12-20 10:32:40", "2016-12-20 10:33:00", 
"2016-12-20 10:33:20", "2016-12-20 10:33:40", "2016-12-20 10:34:00", 
"2016-12-20 10:34:20", "2016-12-20 10:34:40", "2016-12-20 10:35:00", 
"2016-12-20 10:35:20", "2016-12-20 10:35:40", "2016-12-20 10:36:00", 
"2016-12-20 10:37:00", "2016-12-20 10:37:20", "2016-12-20 10:37:40", 
"2016-12-20 10:38:00", "2016-12-20 10:38:20", "2016-12-20 10:40:40", 
"2016-12-20 10:41:20", "2016-12-20 10:41:40", "2016-12-20 10:44:20", 
"2016-12-20 10:44:40", "2016-12-20 10:46:00", "2016-12-20 10:49:40", 
"2016-12-20 10:50:00", "2016-12-20 10:50:20", "2016-12-20 10:55:00", 
"2016-12-20 10:56:00", "2016-12-20 10:57:20", "2016-12-20 10:59:20", 
"2016-12-20 10:59:40", "2016-12-20 11:00:20", "2016-12-20 11:01:20", 
"2016-12-20 11:05:40", "2016-12-20 11:06:00", "2016-12-20 11:07:20", 
"2016-12-20 11:08:20", "2016-12-20 11:08:40", "2016-12-20 11:11:40", 
"2016-12-20 11:12:00", "2016-12-20 11:14:20", "2016-12-20 11:14:40", 
"2016-12-20 11:15:00", "2016-12-20 11:15:20", "2016-12-20 11:15:40", 
"2016-12-20 11:16:00", "2016-12-20 11:16:20", "2016-12-20 11:18:20", 
"2016-12-20 11:18:40", "2016-12-20 11:19:00", "2016-12-20 11:19:20", 
"2016-12-20 11:19:40", "2016-12-20 11:21:20", "2016-12-20 11:21:40", 
"2016-12-20 11:22:20", "2016-12-20 11:22:40", "2016-12-20 11:23:00", 
"2016-12-20 11:23:20", "2016-12-20 11:25:00", "2016-12-20 11:25:20", 
"2016-12-20 11:26:00", "2016-12-20 11:26:40", "2016-12-20 11:27:00", 
"2016-12-20 11:27:20", "2016-12-20 11:27:40", "2016-12-20 11:28:00", 
"2016-12-20 11:28:20", "2016-12-20 11:28:40", "2016-12-20 11:34:40", 
"2016-12-20 11:36:20", "2016-12-20 11:36:40", "2016-12-20 11:41:00", 
"2016-12-20 11:41:20", "2016-12-20 11:42:20", "2016-12-20 11:42:40", 
"2016-12-20 11:46:40", "2016-12-20 11:47:00", "2016-12-20 11:47:20", 
"2016-12-20 11:47:40", "2016-12-20 11:48:00", "2016-12-20 11:48:20", 
"2016-12-20 11:48:40", "2016-12-20 11:54:00", "2016-12-20 11:54:20", 
"2016-12-20 11:57:40", "2016-12-20 12:00:00", "2016-12-20 12:00:40", 
"2016-12-20 12:01:00", "2016-12-20 12:01:20", "2016-12-20 12:01:40", 
"2016-12-20 12:02:20", "2016-12-20 12:02:40", "2016-12-20 12:03:00", 
"2016-12-20 12:03:20", "2016-12-20 12:03:40", "2016-12-20 12:07:00", 
"2016-12-20 12:07:20", "2016-12-20 12:07:40", "2016-12-20 12:08:00", 
"2016-12-20 12:08:20", "2016-12-20 12:10:20", "2016-12-20 12:10:40"
), class = "factor"), b1 = c(-76L, 0L, 0L, 0L, -82L, -74L), b2 = c(-87L, 
-76L, 0L, 0L, 0L, -69L), b3 = c(0L, 0L, -84L, -84L, 0L, -85L), 
    b4 = c(-75L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("TimeStamp", 
"b1", "b2", "b3", "b4"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

head(d2)      
#             TimeStamp  b1  b2  b3  b4
# 1 2016-12-20 12:07:20 -76 -87   0 -75
# 2 2016-12-20 12:07:40   0 -76   0   0
# 3 2016-12-20 12:08:00   0   0 -84   0
# 4 2016-12-20 12:08:20   0   0 -84   0
# 5 2016-12-20 12:10:20 -82   0   0   0
# 6 2016-12-20 12:10:40 -74 -69 -85   0
```

Now I want to have `k` dataframes each one with `n` columns (to be saved as separate csv files). For example, I want to have the below output dataframes `b1, b2, b3, b4` (two of them are shown) from the above input dataframes `d1, d2` as follows:

```
  b1    
  #          TimeStamp  d1  d2
  #2016-12-20 10:17:20 -76  NA
  #2016-12-20 10:19:20   0  NA
  #2016-12-20 10:19:40   0  NA
  #2016-12-20 10:20:00 -76  NA 
  #2016-12-20 10:20:20 -80  NA
  #2016-12-20 10:20:40 -81  NA
  #2016-12-20 12:07:20  NA -76
  #2016-12-20 12:07:40  NA   0
  #2016-12-20 12:08:00  NA   0
  #2016-12-20 12:08:20  NA   0
  #2016-12-20 12:10:20  NA -82
  #2016-12-20 12:10:40  NA -74

  b2    
  #          TimeStamp  d1  d2
  #2016-12-20 10:17:20   0  NA
  #2016-12-20 10:19:20 -74  NA
  #2016-12-20 10:19:40 -79  NA
  #2016-12-20 10:20:00 -73  NA 
  #2016-12-20 10:20:20 -79  NA
  #2016-12-20 10:20:40 -77  NA
  #2016-12-20 12:07:20  NA -87
  #2016-12-20 12:07:40  NA -76
  #2016-12-20 12:08:00  NA   0
  #2016-12-20 12:08:20  NA   0
  #2016-12-20 12:10:20  NA   0
  #2016-12-20 12:10:40  NA -69
```

The timestamps from different dataframes in the given example are disjoint, but the timestamps from different dataframes in general *will overlap*, in the latter case we don't need to fill by NAs (since numeric values will be present).

What is (are) the simplest, the most efficient and the most generalizeble way(s) ways to do this (with `base R / dplyr / tidyr / data.table`, preferably without loops)? I can have the constants `n` and `k` and the dataframes arbitrarily large.

Comment: Maybe something like `Map(data.frame, d1 = d1, d2 = d2)` ?

Comment: Getting this error: `Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  :   arguments imply differing number of rows: 185, 142`, since the dataframes don't have exactly same number of rows. Also, I shall update my post, the problem is slightly more intricate, since it involves timestamps too.

Comment: Yes, you should update your examples then

Comment: @sandipan Please take your time to construct an example with sufficient complexity _before_ posting. Otherwise you waste not only your own time, but more importantly also the time of people trying to help you.

Comment: I think you made a mistake on output on `b1$d2`. Please check

Comment: Are you aware that your "timestamps" are `factor`?

Comment: hmm...Are you sure? Still looks wrong to me. I think you need to re-organise it and include overlapping dates as well as correct expected output. I don't have any more time to spend on this though for the time being.

Comment: @Sotos if the timestamps are overlapped, then we don't need to fill by NAs.

Comment: Not for the overlapping dates but in general yes. But you need to include all such cases in your examples if you want a comprehensive & fairly generic answer

Comment: @docendo discimus yes, they can be converted with strptime / format. But i think it does not matter as far as the goal of the problem is concerned.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try this:

```
#read d1 data from PATH1
d1_df <- read.table("PATH1", header = T, sep = "\t", stringsAsFactors = F)
#store d1 colnames
d1_colname <- colnames(d1_df)[-1]
#read d2 data from PATH2
d2_df <- read.table("PATH2", header = T, sep = "\t", stringsAsFactors = F)
#store d2 colnames
d2_colname <- colnames(d2_df)[-1]
#merge two df timestamp
TimeStamp <-c(unlist(d1[,1]), unlist(d2[,1]))
#merge two df colname
merge_colname <- rbind(d1_colname, d2_colname)
#to match the format want
merge_df <- function(vec_colname){
  d1 <- c(unlist(d1_df[, vec_colname[1]]), rep("NA", nrow(d2_df)))
  d2 <- c(rep("NA", nrow(d1_df)), unlist(d2_df[, vec_colname[2]]))
  return( data.frame(TimeStamp, d1, d2))
}
#get result,but is a list
res_list <- apply(merge_colname, 2, merge_df)
#create data frames from the result
for(i in 1:length(res_list)){
  #bi <- res_list[[i]]
  eval(parse(text=paste0("b",i,"<-res_list[[",i,"]]")))
}
```

And the result:

```
> b1
             TimeStamp  d1  d2
1  2016-12-20 10:17:20 -76  NA
2  2016-12-20 10:19:20   0  NA
3  2016-12-20 10:19:40   0  NA
4  2016-12-20 10:20:00 -76  NA
5  2016-12-20 10:20:20 -80  NA
6  2016-12-20 10:20:40 -81  NA
7  2016-12-20 12:07:20  NA -76
8  2016-12-20 12:07:40  NA   0
9  2016-12-20 12:08:00  NA   0
10 2016-12-20 12:08:20  NA   0
11 2016-12-20 12:10:20  NA -82
12 2016-12-20 12:10:40  NA -74
```

Comment: @sandipan I have updated my answer,you can check it.

Comment: @docendodiscimus Sorry,I will edit my code.